# Django DRF OneToOneField for muliple user types

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement multiple user types in DRF and I'm doing that by having a

1. **User Model** - which has login related fields and common fields in all the roles and also a choice field denoting type of user.
2. **Customer Model** - OneToOneField  with user model.
3. **Seller Model** - OneToOneField  with user model.

I have set up authentication and permissions for User model and now I'm able to log in. I want the logged in user to be able to create his respective profile (based on user_type field of User model).

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ A Generic User inside our system. The fields used are common to all users in system. """
    ....


class Customer(models.Model):
    """A Class to represent a Customer in  System """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to allow a user to create a profile respective to his user_type (customer/seller). and the more confusing part is how do I set the user to current logged in user for my `CustomerSerializer` or `SellerSerializer`

This is the permission class I'm trying to use:

```
class UpdateCustomerProfile(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow users to edit their own profile """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """Check if user is trying to edit their own profile"""

        return obj.user.id == request.user.id
```

and this is the customer serializer:

```
 class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  """A Serizlier class for customer """

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customer
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender')

    def create(self, validated_data):
     """Create and return a new customer."""
```

CustomerViewSet:

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handle creating reading and updating Users in  system"""

    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
    queryset = models.User.objects.filter( user_type = "CS" )
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateCustomerProfile,)
```

But I get an error

> AttributeError at /api/customer-profile/
>   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `CustomerSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'.

I'm new to Django so I'm not sure If this is a way to do it or if I'm doing anything wrong. How can I fix this? Any examples projects following similar strategy would also be very helpful.

Comment: show us how you're using the `CustomerSerializer`.

Comment: @dirkgroten the business logic is something like this:  A user signs up by putting in his mobile,email and password. (user_type set during the sign up, customer or seller). and the next he should proceed to fill his profile details ( so another api endpoint, the endpoint should only allow an authenticated user who has user_type specific to that endpoint )

Comment: I mean show us the code where the serialiazer is instantiated and the full trace so we know on which line of code the error happens

Comment: @dirkgroten right now the code i've posted is only the CustomerSerializer. What happens in browsable API view now is I see a user field with a drop down of all registered user emails. I want this to be automatically set to current user and also before that I want this endpoint to be accessible only if the logged in user if of that user_type

Comment: you need to post the code that causes the error. There isn't code here that can produce the error you're showing. There's no way for us to help if you don't show a [mcve].

Comment: the Serializer expects a `Customer` model but the queryset in your view is for `User`. That's why you're seeing the error.

Comment: @dirkgroten okay the code that causes the error is `    queryset = models.User.objects.filter( user_type = "CS" )` if I pass VD instead of CS the error goes away

Comment: @dirkgroten oh okay!. I was close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your serializer is for a `Customer`, your queryset should be for a `Customer`:

```
queryset = models.Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

for example, if you only want to the `Customer` profile of the current `user`.

Comment: thank you mate. I seek a small advice, is my current approach for multiple user types okay?

Comment: you haven't shown the models in detail, but yes, that's the way to approach it. Different models for each type of profile. Note that a user could be both seller and customer so you should probably allow for that (which your current models do, so that's fine).

Comment: okay. I didn't want to include too much code in my question. But all of the user types have distinct attributes so different model for each is justified. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""Handle creating reading and updating Users in  system"""

serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
#you are using customer model for serializer but for query set you are using 
 #User model.
queryset = models.Customer.objects.filter( user__type = "CS" )
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateCustomerProfile,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey got my code below to work for serializing registration with multiple user types. I followed this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nested-relationships-in-serializers-for-onetoone-fields-in-django-rest-framework-bdb4720d81e6/

here is my models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_individual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_company = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Company(models.Model):
    user                   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company_name           = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

class Individual(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

here is my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from classroom.models import User, Individual, Company
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class IndividualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = ('user', 'email_address')

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('user', 'email_address', 'company_name')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'is_individual', 'is_company')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}



class IndividualRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = ('user', 'email_address')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, 'username': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['user']['username'], validated_data['email_address'], validated_data['user']['password'])
        individual = Individual.objects.create(user=user, email_address=validated_data.pop('email_address'))
        return individual


class CompanyRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('user', 'company_name', 'email_address')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, 'username': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['user']['username'], validated_data['email_address'],
                                        validated_data['user']['password'])
        company = Company.objects.create(user=user, email_address=validated_data.pop('email_address'), company_name=validated_data.pop('company_name'))
        return company

class IndividualLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        individual = authenticate(**data)
        if individual and individual.is_active:
            return individual
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username','password','is_individual','is_company']
        extra_kwargs = {'is_individual': {'required': False},
                        'is_company': {'required': False}}
```

and here is my api.py:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from knox.models import AuthToken
from ..serializers import  \
    UserSerializer, \
    IndividualRegisterSerializer, CompanyRegisterSerializer, \

class RegisterIndividualAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = IndividualRegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        individual = serializer.save()
        individual_data = IndividualSerializer(individual, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
        
        return Response({
             "individual": individual_data,
             "username": individual.user.username,
             "token": AuthToken.objects.create(individual.user)[1]
        })

class RegisterCompanyAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompanyRegisterSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        company = serializer.save()
        company_data = CompanySerializer(company, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
        return Response({
             "company": company_data,
             "username": company.user.username,
             "token": AuthToken.objects.create(company.user)[1]
        })

class LoginCompanyAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompanyLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        company = serializer.validated_data
        company_data = CompanySerializer(company, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
        return Response({
            "company": company_data,
             "username": company.user.username,
             "token": AuthToken.objects.create(company.user)[1]
        })
```

And here is my API POST request's body:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username":"nind5",
        "password": "123456",
        "is_individual" : "True",
        "is_company" : "False"
    },
    "email_address":"n@gmail.com"
}
```

I also used this resource https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d7cIfiydAc&t=437s. Knox is explained in this video as well.

Also, use this online tool to view your db (db.sqlite3) tables : https://sqliteonline.com/

Best,
Nick